# How do I export a remote graph to json using tinkerpop gremlin and neptune?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to export an entire remote graph into json.  When I use the following code, it results in an empty file.  I am using Gremlin-driver 3.3.2 as this is the same version in the underling graph database, AWS Neptune.

```
var traversal = EmptyGraph.instance().traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(getCluster()))
traversal.getGraph().io(graphson()).writeGraph("my-graph.json");
```

How is one supposed to populate the graph with data such that it can be exported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking on-board the valuable feed-back from Ankit and Kelvin, I concentrated on using a local gremlin server to handle the data wrangling.

Once I had the data in a locally running server, by generating gremlin script from an in-memory entity model,I accessed it via a Gremlin console and ran the following:

```
~/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.7/bin/gremlin.sh
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
gremlin> :> graph.io(graphson()).writeGraph("my-graph.json")
==>null
```

This put the `my-graph.json` file in `/opt/gremlin-server/` on the docker container.
I extracted it using `docker cp $(docker container ls -q):/opt/gremlin-server/my-graph.json .`

I can then use this data to populate a gremlin-server testcontainer for running integration tests against a graph database.

Answer (score 3):

The Gremlin io( ) Step is not supported in Neptune. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) is the Neptune's documentation which talks about the other difference between the Amazon Neptune implementation of Gremlin and the TinkerPop implementation.

Comment: so this approach won't work, is there a way to export a graph as json and then load it into a nepture instance?

Comment: I've spun up a docker image running gremlin-server, populated it with data, still unable to get data out of the graph.  I think it's an issue with how I'm getting a reference to the graph.

Answer (score 3):

I also posted this to the Gremlin Users list.

Here's some code that will do it for you with Neptune and should work with most Gremlin Server implementations I would think.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-export

The results of the export can be used to load via Neptune's bulk loader if you choose to export as CSV.

Hope that is useful

If that is more than you needed hopefully it will at least give you some pointers that help.

With  hosted graphs, including Neptune, it is not uncommon to find that they do not expose the Graph object or give access to the io() classes.

Comment: I used the mentioned aws github project and executed the following command which is not showing any result:


<projectFolderOfAwsNeptuneExport>\bin>neptune-export.sh export-pg -e <clusterName>/<Ip>:<port> -d s3://<bucketName>/<folder>

Comment: See new answer from Ian Robinson. The export target needs to be the local file system.

Answer (score 2):

neptune-export doesn't support direct export to S3. You'll have to export to the local file system, and then separately copy the files to S3.